# Twitter blue background in Messages

Tags: twitter, imessage

I've searched and haven't found an answer for this.

In Apple Messages, Twitter links have a light blue background whereas other links don't. Is this something Twitter has figured out how to customize on their end, or is this special treatment from Apple?

[image]
[image]

I'd like to be able to do the same for my app.

EDIT: Here's the only information I've been able to find on Apple's documentation site about how to optimize links for viewing within Messages: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html

EDIT2: Half of the original bounty was auto-awarded but it appears @caaax may be right on the money. This is something Apple and Twitter cooked up together.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is the product of some collaboration from both teams. If you are wondering if you can do this from your side with your own application - I doubt it!

Comment: I was suspecting the same but *really* hoping I was wrong. Ah well, I'll close my question after the bounty ends.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Support Open Graph for rich SMS messages only since iOS 10+, so make sure that the device you are testing the sent text message to is at least iOS 10 (or higher).
The rich previews inside iOS’s iMessage app are generated entirely by a couple of Facebook’s open graph tags, but iMessage only uses 2, “og:title” and “og:image”.
And it is using [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/) and [Twitter Card](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started).

For Facebook image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.j-26.com/assets/facebook.jpg"/>
```

For twitter:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.j-26.com/assets/twitter.jpg"/>
```

Sorry for preview I am not iphone user that is why.

Comment: I know this information already. How do you know Apple is using Twitter Card?